# Is Indy FTP client caching?

Tags: delphi, caching, ftp, indy

Looking at corrupted files on FTP server I think about verifying files uploaded with `TIdFtp.Put` by downloading them just after upload and comparing byte-to byte.

I think that `TIdFtp` may be theoretically caching data and return it from cache instead of actually downloading.

Please allay or confirm my concerns.

Comment: I don't think it is. What is that assumption based on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no caching, as there is no such thing in the FTP protocol in general. `TIdFTP` deals only with live data.

Are you, perhaps, uploading binary files in ASCII mode? If so, that would alter line break characters (CR and LF) during transmission. That is a common mistake to make, since ASCII is FTP's default mode. Make sure you are setting the `TIdFTP.TransferType` property as needed before transferring a file.  ASCII mode should only be used for text files, if used at all.

And FWIW, you may not need to download a file to verify its bytes. If the server supports any `X<Hash>` commands (where `Hash` can be `SHA512`, `SHA256`, `SHA1`, `MD5`, or `CRC`) , `TIdFTP` has `VerifyFile()` methods to use them.  That calculates a hash of a local file and then compares it to a hash calculated by the server for a remote file.  No transfer of file data is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is nothing wrong with Indy or data being set. Customers just have very expensive, slow and unstable Internet connections by default and I have to put up with it. I am sending all the files in binary mode, even the text-based ones. I have to work with any FTP server. This time it is Pure-FTPd. Not all files are corrupted, but just about 5...7 of 1000...2000. There are skipped and unprintable characters right in the middle of XML. I will give a try to VerifyFile().